# Is it possible to extend the Button class and have it implement it's own OnClick listener?

Tags: java, android, listener

Through my research in the question about getting button listeners across Activities and Fragments, the common response is to interface your listener and implement it in each the Fragments/Activities.

However, as long as your listener is generic (or global, affecting all buttons), this is redundant.

So enter in implementation idea 2:
I could extend my own Button class and implement the OnTouch listener.  Sounds great in theory, but I'm not sure how to actually set the listener in this state.  Is this on the right track, or is there a better way that I'm missing here?  The only other option I thought of would be creating a different class that implements the listener, but I didn't want to instantiate the class every time I make a new button.

This is my idea:

```java
public final class EffectsButton extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public EffectsButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EffectsButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            handleButtonEffect(v, "onTouch.down");
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
            handleButtonEffect(v, "onTouch.up");

        return false;
    }

    public static void handleButtonEffect(View view, String listenerType) {
        if (listenerType.equals("onTouch.down")) {
            view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        } else if (listenerType.equals("onTouch.up") || listenerType.equals("onClick")) {
            view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
        }

        view.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```java
// onCreate();

MyButton button = findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
button.setOnTouchListener(/* what to do here? */);
```

Comment: The question seems silly now that I found the answer, but I'll leave this up for anyone on the same path to clean code that I'm on.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the answer.

All you have to do is refer to itself:

```java
MyButton button = findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
button.setOnTouchListener(button);
```